# how to watch the cilent when it lose Leadership through zookeeper curator?

Tags: apache-zookeeper, apache-curator

**as we know,when the client get  the leadership,will invode the takeLeadership,but the document do not tell me when the client lost the leadership!!!so,how to watch the cilent when it lose Leadership through zookeeper  curator?**

**question two : why my client was lose,i am can not debug the stateChanged(...) thought idea?**

**here my code, expect your great answer,thx**

public class ExampleClient  extends LeaderSelectorListenerAdapter implements Closeable{

```
private final String name;
private final LeaderSelector  leaderSelector;
private final AtomicInteger leaderCount = new AtomicInteger();//用于记录领导次数

public ExampleClient(CuratorFramework client,String path,String name) {
    this.name = name;
    leaderSelector = new LeaderSelector(client, path, this);
    leaderSelector.autoRequeue();//保留重新获取领导权资格
}

public void start() throws IOException {
    leaderSelector.start();
}


@Override
public void close() throws IOException {
    leaderSelector.close();
}


@Override
public void stateChanged(CuratorFramework client, ConnectionState newState)
{
    if ((newState == ConnectionState.SUSPENDED) || (newState == ConnectionState.LOST) ) {

        log.info("stateChanged !!!");

        throw new CancelLeadershipException();
    }
}

/**
 * will be invoded when get leadeship
 * @param client
 * @throws Exception
 */
@Override
public void takeLeadership(CuratorFramework client) throws Exception {
    final int waitSeconds =(int)(Math.random()*5)+1;
    log.info(name + " is  the leader now,wait " + waitSeconds + " seconds!");
    log.info(name + " had been leader for " + leaderCount.getAndIncrement() + " time(s) before");
    try {
      /**/
        Thread.sleep(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(waitSeconds));

        //do something!!!

        /*while(true){
            //guarantee this client be the leader all the time!
        }*/
    }catch (InterruptedException e){
        log.info(name+" was interrupted!");
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    }finally{
        log.info(name+" relinquishing leadership.\n");
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Your comment "guarantee this client be the leader all the time!" cannot be true. If there is a network partition you cannot be certain that you are leader anymore. Also, you shouldn't override stateChanged() from LeaderSelectorListenerAdapter. The point of using LeaderSelectorListenerAdapter is for its stateChanged() behavior.

Lastly - your English is very hard to understand - I apologize that I don't understand your main questions.

Answer (score 0):

LeaderLatchListener has two call backs about isLeader and notLeader. Some examples, 
http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=org.apache.curator.framework.recipes.leader.LeaderLatchListener